# Display a sequence of images with next and previous buttons in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a sequence of images that I want to display them one by one and allow the user to navigate between the images using next and previous buttons in matplotlib.
Here is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()


class Index(object):
   ind = 0

   def next(self, event):
    self.ind += 1
    print self.ind
    orig_frame = cv2.imread(FFMPEG_PATH + all_frames[self.ind])
    ax.imshow(orig_frame)


   def prev(self, event):
    self.ind -= 1
    orig_frame = cv2.imread(FFMPEG_PATH + all_frames[self.ind])
    ax.imshow(orig_frame)


callback = Index()
axnext = plt.axes([0.8, 0.7, 0.1, 0.075])
axprev = plt.axes([0.8, 0.6, 0.1, 0.075])
next_button = Button(axnext, 'Next')
next_button.on_clicked(callback.next)
prev_button = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
prev_button.on_clicked(callback.prev)


plt.show()
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

The problem is that as soon as I click the next button, it does not display anything and the program terminates immediately. What should I do?